# Wrapper class to get pairs in range-for loop

Tags: c++, wrapper, stl

This code implements a simple wrapper, intended to be used with range-for to manipulate items of a container as overlapping pairs, ie. 3 items will give 2 pairs.

Code review focus: Is `pair_range` good modern C++? Any easily avoidable performance issues, like unnecessary copies?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

#include <iterator>
#include <optional>
#include <utility>

template<class V, template<class...> class C>
class pair_range {
public:
    struct pair_iterator {
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type   = ssize_t;
        using value_type        = std::pair<V, V>;
        using pointer           = ssize_t;
        using reference         = std::pair<V, V>; // no actual reference available

        pair_iterator(const pair_range & sequence, pointer index = 0)
            : m_sequence(sequence)
            , m_index(index) {
        };

        const reference operator*() const {
            return value_type{m_sequence.at(m_index), m_sequence.at(m_index+1)};
        }
        //operator->() not possible because pairs are not lvalues

         // prefix increment
        auto &operator++() {
            m_index++;
            return *this;
        }

        // postfix increment
        auto operator++(int) {
            auto tmp = *this;
            ++(*this);
            return tmp;
        }

        friend bool operator== (const pair_iterator &a, const pair_iterator &b) {
            return a.m_index == b.m_index && a.m_sequence.has_same_container(b.m_sequence);
        };

        friend bool operator!= (const pair_iterator &a, const pair_iterator &b) {
            return a.m_index != b.m_index || !a.m_sequence.has_same_container(b.m_sequence);
        };

    private:
        const pair_range &m_sequence;
        pointer m_index = 0;

    };

    pair_range(const C<V> &source) : m_source_ptr(&source) {
        const std::type_info &ti = typeid(*this);
        std::cout << "&-constructor, type=" << ti.name() << std::endl;
    }
    pair_range(const C<V> &&source) : m_source_copy(std::move(source)), m_source_ptr(&m_source_copy.value()) {
        const std::type_info &ti = typeid(*this);
        std::cout << "&&-constructor, type=" << ti.name() << std::endl;
    }

    pair_iterator begin() const {
        return pair_iterator{*this};
    }
    pair_iterator end() const {
        auto size = m_source_ptr->size();
        auto end = static_cast<typename pair_iterator::pointer>(size == 0 ? 0 : size - 1);
        return pair_iterator{*this, end};
    }

    bool has_same_container(const pair_range &other) const {
        return m_source_ptr == other.m_source_ptr;
    }

private:
    const V &at(typename pair_iterator::pointer index) const {
        return (*m_source_ptr)[index];
    }

    const std::optional<const C<V> > m_source_copy;
    const C<V> * const m_source_ptr = nullptr;
};

// test code

#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <variant>

template <class T>
void printPair(const T &pair)
{
    const std::type_info &ti = typeid(pair);
    std::cout  << std::get<0>(pair) << ' ' << std::get<1>(pair)
               << ", type=" << ti.name() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "--- empty list ---\n";
    const std::vector<int> list1{};
    for(auto pair : pair_range(list1)) {
        printPair(pair);
    }

    std::cout << "--- 1 elements ---\n";
    for(auto &pair : pair_range( std::vector{1} )) {
        printPair(pair);
    }

    std::cout << "--- 2 elements ---\n";
    std::vector xy{ std::string("x"), std::string("y") };
    for(auto &pair : pair_range(xy)) {
        printPair(pair);
    }

    std::cout << "--- 4 elements ---\n";
    const std::string abcd = {"abcd"};
    for(const std::tuple<char, char> &pair : pair_range(abcd)) {
        printPair(pair);
    }
}
```

Here's the output of that code on my machine:

```
--- empty list ---
&-constructor, type=10pair_rangeIiSt6vectorE
--- 1 elements ---
&&-constructor, type=10pair_rangeIiSt6vectorE
--- 2 elements ---
&-constructor, type=10pair_rangeINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESt6vectorE
x y, type=St4pairINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES5_E
--- 4 elements ---
&-constructor, type=10pair_rangeIcNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringEE
a b, type=St5tupleIJccEE
b c, type=St5tupleIJccEE
c d, type=St5tupleIJccEE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::cout << "&-constructor, type=" << ti.name() << std::endl;
```

For this debugging output, consider using `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` (MSVC calls it `__FUNCSIG__`) instead of `std::type_info`. On GCC, your way prints

```
&-constructor, type=10pair_rangeIiSt6vectorE
&&-constructor, type=10pair_rangeIiSt6vectorE
```

whereas a simple `std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';` prints

```
pair_range<V, C>::pair_range(const C<V>&) [with V = int; C = std::vector]
pair_range<V, C>::pair_range(const C<V>&&) [with V = int; C = std::vector]
```

---

Consider naming it `pair_range::iterator` instead of `pair_range::pair_iterator`.

Consider naming it `adjacent_pairs_range` instead of just `pair_range`; the operation here is pretty similar to what happens inside `std::adjacent_find` and `std::adjacent_difference`. In fact, a great test of this code would be for you to reimplement `std::adjacent_find` in terms of `std::find`-over-an-`adjacent_pairs_range`!

---

Your `pair_range` is trying to do something weird where if you pass its constructor an lvalue it captures a pointer to the lvalue, but if you pass it an rvalue it captures a copy of the rvalue *and* a pointer to its own copy. There are at least three things wrong here:

1. [Value category is not lifetime.](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/03/11/value-category-is-not-lifetime/) It's extremely easy to create a dangling `pair_range`, and worse, in some common cases where the user might *think* they were creating a dangling `pair_range`, the code happens to work anyway! It's hard to form a correct mental model of what's going on with this type.
2. Capturing a pointer into yourself is never a great idea. It generally means that you need to follow the Rule of Three (or Five), instead of the Rule of Zero, because copying or moving such an object won't update its internal pointer-to-self.

   ```
    for (auto&& p : pair_range(std::vector{1,2,3}))
        // OK

    for (auto&& p : std::identity()(pair_range(std::vector{1,2,3})))
        // UB, prints garbage
   ```

For a simpler mental model, and a simpler implementation (more efficient *and* twice as easy to unit-test), I recommend giving your type only a constructor from `const R&` and *always* capturing a pointer to that lvalue. Let the caller worry about making sure the lvalue lives long enough to be used; and let the caller *forget* about any value-category-related gotchas built into `pair_range`. (This is the Unix philosophy, btw: simple, composable tools that do *one* thing, instead of being able to do *two* things and always having to guess which of them the user wants.)

3. Typo or misunderstanding (or both) here:

   ```
    pair_range(const C<V> &&source) :
        m_source_copy(std::move(source)), m_source_ptr(&m_source_copy.value()) {
    }
   ```

Since `source` here is a reference to a const-qualified `C<V>`, there's really no point in trying to *move* from it. `std::move` is for when you have an rvalue that you *can* pilfer the guts of, i.e., `source` should be non-const-qualified.

Also, all of these constructors should be `explicit` as a matter of course. The only reason to create a non-explicit ("implicit") constructor in C++ is when you want implicit conversion, either from a single argument (e.g. `myBignum = 42` instead of `myBignum = Bignum(42)`) or from a braced sequence (e.g. `myPair = {'x', 42}` instead of `myPair = Pair('x', 42)`, or `myWidget = {}` instead of `myWidget = Widget()`).

---

```
//operator->() not possible because pairs are not lvalues
```

It's possible; you need the [arrow proxy idiom](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/02/06/arrow-proxy/). And I think it's worth doing, because if I've got an iterator `it` that points into a range of pairs, you *know* I'm going to want to access `it->first` and `it->second`. If I can't do that, it's going to be annoying.

---

As JDługosz mentioned, you can omit `operator!=` in C++20; and even in C++17, it's probably more readable *in this case* to implement its body as `return !(a == b);`.

---

Your `pair_iterator` has a data member of reference type. Never use data members of const or reference type! In this particular case, it bites you by making `pair_iterator`'s assignment operator implicitly deleted (because references are not rebindable). So `pair_iterator` does not satisfy C++20's `input_or_output_iterator` concept.

Here's some good C++20 advice: If you're trying to implement a type that satisfies some library concept, such as "This type is an iterator" or "This type is a contiguous range" or "This type is regular" or "This type is three-way comparable" — `static_assert` is your friend!

```
static_assert(std::input_or_output_iterator<adjacent_pair_range<int[10]>::iterator>);
```

If that assertion fails, you know you have work to do.

...And waitaminute, what the heck is going on with these template parameters?!

```
template<class V, template<class...> class C>
class pair_range {
```

No no no. It should look more like

```
template<class R>
class adjacent_pair_range {
```

where `R` is the type of the range to which you're capturing a pointer.

---

Your `pointer` type shouldn't be `ssize_t`; that's an integer type. Use `std::pair<V,V>*` or perhaps just `void` (does that work? I haven't tested). Alternatively, in C++20 and later, just omit `pointer` because nobody cares anymore.

Your `operator*` returns `const reference`, which is wrong: [returning "by const value" is never meaningful](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/01/03/const-is-a-contract/#guidelines-for-reliably-const-correct-code), and if `reference` actually *were* a reference type (which it's not), then `const reference` would be exactly the same type as `reference` (because all references are const themselves; what you might have meant here was "reference *to* const," but that's not the same thing).

Once you implement the arrow proxy idiom, your `reference` type will end up being `std::pair<V&, V&>`. This is good because it allows people to iterate over *and mutate* their ranges, like this:

```
template<class R>
void inclusive_scan(R&& r) {
    for (auto&& pair : adjacent_pairs_range(r)) {
        pair->second += pair->first;
    }
}

std::vector<int> v = {3,1,4,1,5};
inclusive_scan(v);
assert(( v == std::vector<int>{3,4,8,9,14} ));
```

---

I recommend fixing all this stuff — and whatever more you need to fix in order to make your type model `forward_range`; remember to use `static_assert` liberally in your test cases — and then ask a new question to get more reviews. :)

Answer (score 1):

I thought this exact feature was in Eric's Ranges v3 library, but I don't see it in the C++20 docs.  You might look at the original library to find it.  (It *might* be `adjecent_view` noted for C++23, but cppreference doesn't explain it)

---

I always use Boost's iterator facade and iterator adaptor helpers to do anything like this.  Then you don't have to write all the details, but just fill in the interesting function.

In C++20, `operator!=` will be autogenerated from `==`.

[⧺SL.io.50](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#slio50-avoid-endl) Don't use `endl`.

Comment: Those `std::endl` are used with purpose to flush the stream. Should really use `std::cerr`; instead, actually.

Comment: @hyde: Because misuse of `std::endl` has become endemic, I usually recommend `<< '\n' << std::flush` instead, to convey to readers that you really intend to flush the stream.  Slightly more typing, but saves time handling the review feedback!